# Logic to print month according to selected month in table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date, dom-events

I'm getting signin time and signout time but both are simultaneously means when I click on signin signout time becoming empty when I click on signout time signin time becoming empty this happening because using two different functions `onSigninClick()` and `onSignoutClick()` for different buttons. How can I print both without loosing another value and also for total hours also please help me with the code in Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
 
  <title>Employee Attendance</title>
 </head>
<body background="b.jpg">
 <center>
  <div align="right">
   <button onclick="onSigninClick()">Signin</button>
   <button onClick="onSignoutClick()">Signout</button>
</div>
 Month:
  <select name="month" id="month" onchange="getMonth(this.value)">
   <option value="">Select Month</option>
   <option value="0">January</option>
   <option value="1">February</option>
   <option value="2">March</option>
   <option value="3">April</option>
   <option value="4">May</option>
   <option value="5">June</option>
   <option value="6">July</option>
   <option value="7">August</option>
   <option value="8">September</option>
   <option value="9">October</option>
   <option value="10">Novermber</option>
   <option value="11">December</option>
  </select>
<table id="monData" border="" cellpadding="15">
 <tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Sign In</th>
  <th>Sign Out</th>
  <th>Total Hours</th>
 </tr>
</table>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function onSigninClick(){
    
     var now = new Date();
 var time = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes();
 document.getElementById("month").value= now.getMonth()
 getMonth(now.getMonth())
 document.getElementById("signin" + now.getDate()).innerHTML = time;

 }
 function onSignoutClick(){
     var now = new Date();
     var time = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes();
     document.getElementById("month").value= now.getMonth()
     getMonth(now.getMonth())
     document.getElementById("signout" + now.getDate()).innerHTML = time;
 }
 
 function get_days_in_month(month,year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
 }

function getMonth(selected_month){  
 var current_year = new Date().getFullYear()
 var selected_month = (parseInt(selected_month)+1)
 if(month=="")
  alert("Please select Month");
 else{
  var finTab="<tr><th>Date</th><th>Sign In</th><th>Sign Out</th><th>Total Hours</th></tr>";
  var days_in_month = get_days_in_month(selected_month,current_year);
  //alert(days_in_month); 
  for(i =1;i<=days_in_month;i++){
    finTab = finTab + "<tr>";
    finTab = finTab + "<td>"+i+"/" + selected_month   + "/" + current_year + "</td><td id=signin" + i + "></td><td id=signout" + i + "></td><td></td>";
    finTab = finTab + "<tr>";
  } 
  document.getElementById("monData").innerHTML = finTab;
 }  
}    
</script>     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ravi says, the month values are better to be the month number rather than the number of days in the month. Also, if you're going to have multiple submit buttons, better to put the controls in a form and give the buttons a name so you can tell which one was clicked.

I'd use a tbody for the rows so that you don't have to regenerate the header each time. You can even set the number of cells in the new rows to be whatever the number of cells are in the header row so you can adjust the number of cells without having to adjust the function. You could also put a class on the date header cell so you know which column to put the date into.

I've used a thead for the header row, but you could just use another tbody (a table can have multiple tbodies).

E.g.

```js
// Helper to format a date as DD/MM/YYYY
function formatDate(d) {
  var z = x => ('0'+x).slice(-2);
  return z(d.getDate()) + '/' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
}

function getMonth(month) {
  // Get the monData tbody and clear the rows
  var tbody = document.getElementById('monData');
  while (tbody.rows.length) {
    tbody.removeChild(tbody.firstChild);
  }

  // Get the header row, number of cells and date cell index
  // The default date cell is 0 (the first one)
  var headRow = tbody.parentNode.rows[0];
  var cellCount = headRow.cells.length;
  var dateIndex = headRow.querySelector('.dateCell').cellIndex || 0;
  
  // If selected first option, stop here
  if (month == 0) return;
  
  // Create a date for the start of the selected month in the current year
  var date = new Date();
  month -= 1;
  date.setMonth(month, 1);

  // Create a document fragment with the required tr and tds
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var oRow = frag.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));

  for (var i=0; i<cellCount; i++) {
    oRow.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
  }

  // Clone the row once for each day of the month, putting a 
  // formatted date in the first cell
  while (date.getMonth() == month) {
    var row = oRow.cloneNode(true);
    row.cells[dateIndex].textContent = formatDate(date);
    frag.appendChild(row);
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
  }
  
  // Append the fragment of rows to the tbody
  tbody.appendChild(frag);
}
```

```css
table {
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-top : 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom : 1px solid #dddddd;
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div align="right">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="signIn">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Out" name="signOut">
  </div>
  Month:<select name="month" id="month" onchange="getMonth(this.value)">
    <option value="0">Select Month</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>
</form>
<table>
  <head>
    <tr><th class="dateCell">Date</th><th>Sign In</th><th>Sign Out</th><th>Total Hours</th></tr>
  </head>
  <tbody id="monData">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have done a few changes in option values instead of days in each month have just assigned the values of month starting from  0 to 11.  And used the js datetime
object `new Date()` to get the current year, date and time using `getFullyear()` `getDate()`.

`function get_days_in_month(month,year)` you can call this function which will return the total days in that particular month takes 2 args as month and year.

Clicking Sign In Button will call  `onSigninClick()`. Where the Month value will be set to the current month in case the user has selected other month and have called `getMonth()` which will render the table of the current month. Also, have assigned a var time with the current time when the Sign in button is clicked with the value in HH:MM:SS format.

```
finTab = finTab + "<td>"+i+"/" + selected_month   + "/" + current_year + "</td><td id=signin_" + i + "></td><td></td><td></td>"
```

The value will be print to the particular day row using the column id that I have assigned in the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Employee Attendance</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <center>
  <div align="right">
   <button onclick="onSigninClick()">Sign In</button>
   <button>Sign out</button>
</div>
 Month: 
  <select name="month" id="month" onchange="getMonth(this.value)">
   <option value="">Select Month</option>
   <option value="0">January</option>
   <option value="1">February</option>
   <option value="2">March</option>
   <option value="3">April</option>
   <option value="4">May</option>
   <option value="5">June</option>
   <option value="6">July</option>
   <option value="7">August</option>
   <option value="8">September</option>
   <option value="9">October</option>
   <option value="10">Novermber</option>
   <option value="11">December</option>
  </select>
<table id="monData" border="" cellpadding="15">
 <tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Sign In</th>
  <th>Sign Out</th>
  <th>Total Hours</th>
 </tr>
</table>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">

//  Will be called on Click of Signin Button
 function onSigninClick(){
 var now = new Date(); //  javascript datetime object 
 var time = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();  // Time in HH:MM:SS format 
 document.getElementById("month").value= now.getMonth()  // Set the value of Select Tag
 getMonth(now.getMonth())  // Update the table based on current month
 document.getElementById("signin_" + now.getDate()).innerHTML = time  // print the signin date on respective date
}

// function to get total days in a particular month
 function get_days_in_month(month,year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
 };

// function to render the month table
function getMonth(selected_month){  
 var current_year = new Date().getFullYear() // current year 
 var selected_month = (parseInt(selected_month)+1)  // selected month 

 if(!month)  // if month not selected alert user
  alert("Please select Month");
 else{
  var finTab="<tr><th>Date</th><th>Sign In</th><th>Sign Out</th><th>Total Hours</th></tr>";
  var days_in_month = get_days_in_month(selected_month,current_year)
  for(i =1;i<=days_in_month;i++){
    finTab = finTab + "<tr>";
    finTab = finTab + "<td>"+i+"/" + selected_month   + "/" + current_year + "</td><td id=signin_" + i + "></td><td></td><td></td>";
    finTab = finTab + "<tr>";
  } 
  document.getElementById("monData").innerHTML = finTab;  // will push the string in the element.
 }  
}    
</script>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A good answer should include why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. Just posting code doesn’t do that.

Comment: hi Subhanshu Pandey Sir similarly i have created for onSignoutClick() its working fine but when i click **Signin** **Signout** value is changing to empty when i click on **Signout** **Signin** cell value becoming empty please help me with the code sir

Comment: @RaviChandrathangallapally What have you written  in the function when user clicks on Signout. ? And as you are saying "but when i click Signin Signout value is changing to empty"  what should be happening in this condition if working corectly ?